# Limits on number of fields to be indexed for Salesforce Big Objects

Tags: indexing, custom-index, big-object

Does Salesforce have any limits on indexing the number of fields on a Big Object?

The example in the latest Big Object guide indexes 3 fields. Does anyone know, whats the governor limit on number of indexes, if any?

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/big_objects_guide.pdf

Comment: Docs suggest they're the same as normal field limits, so probably just about the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon this knowledge base article it looks like the limit is 5 as Geoff Rothman reported.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_bo_considerations.htm&type=5

Quoting in case this link ever dies:

"Keep these considerations in mind when creating the index.

- An index must include at least one custom field and can have up to five custom fields total."

Answer (score 1):

As of today, the limit for indexes in a bigobject is 5

Comment: Do you have a source to corroborate this? Your answer seems to be at odds with the accepted answer.